# What is “Microsoft C++ Visual Runtime Library: Runtime error!”

Tags: c++, windows

I am getting this error after my application has been running for about 4 hours. I have no idea why this is occurring. The error occurs on windows 7 and windows XP systems. Sorry I dont have anymore information. I just get this error message after about 4 ours of my application running:

Microsoft C++ Visual Runtime Library

Runtime error!

Program: XXXXX.exe

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Any help would be amazing, thanks.

All the best

Comment: Probably some NULL pointer access, or perhaps a memory issue. Have you tried replicating this under the debugger with all exceptions turned on?

Comment: You should contact the application's support team for more information. Send them your core dump and they'll be very grateful. If you *are* the support team, use a debugger.

Comment: I can't post an answer without just reiterating what @crashmstr said.  **It's telling you that you're not using a debugger, and a debugger is needed to diagnose the problem.**

Answer (score 2):

The terminate() function was called.  MSDN documents the following possibilities:

- A matching catch handler cannot be found for a thrown C++ exception.
- An exception is thrown by a destructor function during stack unwind.
- The stack is corrupted after throwing an exception.

Getting a repro for this in the Debug build ought to be your priority.

Answer (score 0):

Run the application in the MSVC++ debugger; when the crash occurs, you'll have much more information about what's happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will run it through the debugger and see what info I get.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue. I was creating dynamic objects and storing them within a vector. During any point, the object would be erased if the criteria for removal was met. The issue was I was only erasing the contents of the iterator and not deleting the dynamic object. This caused a massive memory leak, which in turn resulted in the crash. I corrected the issue and now it runs fine.

Thanks for your help.

All the best,
Martin